# Perimeter of a triangle inside a rectangular solid? (SAT Math 1)

Tags: triangles, solid-geometry

I'm going through an SAT Math Level 1 textbook, by the Princeton Review. In the solid geometry section, there's a question which seems fairly straight-forward, yet after spending quite a while on it, even checking their answer guide, I am unable to grasp the process they've used to come by their answer.

question:
[image: Here is the question.]
answer:
[image: Here are the book's answer and explanation.]

My answer was 30.12. I used the Pythagorean theorem thrice:
(4^2 + 3^2)^0.5 + (12^2 + 4^2)^0.5 + (3^2 + 12^2)^0.5
I saw the sides of triangle EDB as hypotenuses of each face, so I used the other sides of their corresponding right-angled triangles (the length, width, and height of the solid shape) to find the three sides.

How is this incorrect? And, how did they get a 5-12-13 triangle for BE?

Comment: added ! in front of the links to make them the images in case you are wondering.

Comment: The answer provided is wrong. Your approach is correct.  The diagonal through the center of the prism would be 13  (DF or BH).  But that is not part of your triangle.

Comment: Sometimes the review books mess up. Kudos to you for questioning a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These are the numbers that I got.